# Onclick hiding and open the selected content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a code

**html**

```
<a href="#" id="show_spoiler" onClick="showContent('video.php#01')">Видео 1</a> <a href="#" id="hide_spoiler" onClick="hideContent()" style="display: none">Закрыть видео</a> <div id="content"></div> <div id="loading" style="display: none">Идет загрузка...</div>

<a href="#" id="show_spoiler" onClick="showContent('video.php#02')">Видео 2</a> <a href="#" id="hide_spoiler" onClick="hideContent()" style="display: none">Закрыть видео</a> <div id="content"></div> <div id="loading" style="display: none">Идет загрузка...</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function showContent(link) {
    var cont = document.getElementById('content'); 
    var loading = document.getElementById('loading');
        $('#hide_spoiler').css('display','block');
        $('#show_spoiler').css('display','none');
    cont.innerHTML = loading.innerHTML;
    if( http )  
    { http.open('get', link);
        http.onreadystatechange = function ()  
        {   if(http.readyState == 4)  
            {   cont.innerHTML = http.responseText;  }    } 
        http.send(null);
        } 
    else  
    {  document.location = link;   }  } 
// ajax объект
function createRequestObject()  
{  try { return new XMLHttpRequest() } 
    catch(e)  
    {  try { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP') } 
        catch(e)  
        {   try { return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') } 
            catch(e) { return null; }   } } }

    function hideContent() { 
    var cont = document.getElementById('content');
        $('#hide_spoiler').css('display','none');
        $('#show_spoiler').css('display','block');
    cont.innerHTML = '';   
    } 
// ajax объект
```

The problem is that pressing any of the buttons "open": the first only reacts and under it displays content from all the buttons. Help please, what to do to each button are their content ... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID attributes are [supposed to be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2). With multiple the response is not even very likely to be remotely cross browser or even browser version the same.

A better way to do that would be:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="show_spoiler_1" onClick="showContent('video.php#01',1)">Видео 1</a>
<a href="#" id="hide_spoiler_1" onClick="hideContent(1)" style="display: none">Закрыть видео</a>
<div id="content_1"></div>
<div id="loading_1" style="display: none">Идет загрузка...</div>

<a href="#" id="show_spoiler_2" onClick="showContent('video.php#02',2)">Видео 2</a>
<a href="#" id="hide_spoiler_2" onClick="hideContent(2)" style="display: none">Закрыть видео</a>
<div id="content_2"></div>
 <div id="loading_2" style="display: none">Идет загрузка...</div>
```

JS:

```
function showContent(link,ref) {
    var cont = document.getElementById('content_' + ref); 
    var loading = document.getElementById('loading_' + ref);
        $('#hide_spoiler_' + ref).css('display','block');
        $('#show_spoiler_' + ref).css('display','none');
    cont.innerHTML = loading.innerHTML;
    if( http )  
    { http.open('get', link);
        http.onreadystatechange = function ()  
        {   if(http.readyState == 4)  
            {   cont.innerHTML = http.responseText;  }    } 
        http.send(null);
        } 
    else  
    {  document.location = link;   }  } 
// ajax объект
function createRequestObject()  
{  try { return new XMLHttpRequest() } 
    catch(e)  
    {  try { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP') } 
        catch(e)  
        {   try { return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') } 
            catch(e) { return null; }   } } }

    function hideContent(ref) { 
    var cont = document.getElementById('content_' + ref);
        $('#hide_spoiler_' + ref).css('display','none');
        $('#show_spoiler_' + ref).css('display','block');
    cont.innerHTML = '';   
    }
```

I'm curious as to why you are using that complicated AJAX query instead of the jQuery nice simple [AJAX calls](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)?

Comment: I was given an assignment to write part of the site, and time for the normal study was not. And Sorry if I'm doing the simplest errors in the code.

Comment: yeah I know well how the lack of time is the cause of so many simple errors that cause so much annoyance ;)